# Bash string formatting/substitution

Tags: bash

I have 2 variable in a bash script that look like this:

```
key='fox'

string='The quick brown jumps over the lazy dog'
```

I'd like to create a new variable where `key` is inserted between the words `brown` and `jumps`. How can I do this in bash? I was trying something like this, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
sentence='The quick brown ${key} jumps over the lazy dog'
```

The variable of sentence should be:

```
string='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write:

```
sentence="The quick brown ${key} jumps over the lazy dog"
```

using double-quotes instead of single-quotes. (Parameter expansion, and all other substitutions, are disabled within single-quotes; see [§3.1.2.2 "Single Quotes" in *The Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes).)